# Flex s:datagrid sorting doesn't seem to work

Tags: apache-flex, sorting, datagrid, flash-builder

I'm using Flashbuilder 4.6 and can't get sorting of columns in my s:DataGrid to work, clicking on the columns does nothing.  Can anyone suggest what is wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:DataGrid x="30" y="24" requestedRowCount="4" sortableColumns="true">
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="dataField1" headerText="Column 1"></s:GridColumn>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="dataField2" headerText="Column 2"></s:GridColumn>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="dataField3" headerText="Column 3"></s:GridColumn>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:columns>
        <s:typicalItem>
            <fx:Object dataField1="Sample Data" dataField2="Sample Data" dataField3="Sample Data"></fx:Object>
        </s:typicalItem>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <fx:Object dataField1="4" dataField2="c" dataField3="data1"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object dataField1="2" dataField2="d" dataField3="data2"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object dataField1="1" dataField2="a" dataField3="data3"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object dataField1="3" dataField2="b" dataField3="data4"></fx:Object>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:DataGrid>

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of the type of your `dataProvider` which you should change to `ArrayCollection`. `ArrayList` is basically a "lighter" version of `ArrayCollection` stripped of sort and filter functionalities and those are used in the background by `DataGrid` when you click column header for sorting.

Comment: Thank you, very precise answer.

Comment: Good answer means good question: so vote for the question too :-)